# Insert line after matching line in sshd inside pam.d

Tags: sed, awk

I want to insert a line after matching line in sshd file which is present inside pam.d directory.

For e.g. it should search for this line

```
account    required     pam_nologin.so
```

and it should insert a line

```
account    required     pam_access.so
```

just below it, with proper line spacing between words.

I'm new to sed and awk, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work (reading from stdin, printing to stdout for testin purposes):

```
sed -e '/^account    required     pam_nologin\.so$/a account    required     pam_access.so'
```

the `a` command will **a**ppend the text to the matched line, the matched line being one consisting of exactly "account    required     pam_nologin.so".

If you want to use the `-i` switch (edit a file in-place), I strongly suggest using `-i .bak` or similar to keep a backup of the original file:

```
sed -i .bak -e '/^account    required     pam_nologin\.so$/a account    required     pam_access.so' /etc/pam.d/sshd
```

Answer (score 1):

Using good old `ed`:

```
ed /etc/pam.d/sshd << EOT
/account    required     pam_nologin.so/
a
account    required     pam_access.so
.
w
EOT
```

The `/account    required     pam_nologin.so/` addresses a line.

The `a` command is for appending text to the editor buffer.

The text `account    required     pam_access.so` is entered into the buffer.

`.` returns to command mode.

`w` write out buffer to file.

Comment: I needed to use sed merely, though I really appreciate your help, will try it somewhere. Thanks.